# Worst-case time complexity of inserting an integral into Python's dict() considering adversarial input

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, hash, time-complexity

We all know the time complexity of inserting something into a hash set is *on average* O(1). However, I'm focusing on the *worst-case* behavior. I mean, there must exist a specific sequence of integral keys which can trigger many hash collisions when the elements are inserted successively, and that's the "worst case" I was referring to.

More concretely:

- What's the worst-case complexity of inserting an key-value pair to a dictionary with respect to N, the number of existing items in the dictionary?
- What's the corresponding adversarial input?

Here is my work so far

```
from time import time
from math import log2


dummy = {}
elapsed = float('inf')
for k in range(20, 38):
    tic = time()
    dummy[1<<(1<<k)] = k
    elapsed, last = time() - tic, elapsed
    print(f"{k=}, {elapsed=:.4f}, {elapsed/last=:.4f}")
```

The adversarial input above apparently results in a time complexity of O(N^2)... or maybe it's O(N^2*ln(N))? I cannot tell.

```
k=20, elapsed=0.0002, elapsed/last=0.0000
k=21, elapsed=0.0004, elapsed/last=2.1508
k=22, elapsed=0.0007, elapsed/last=1.8340
k=23, elapsed=0.0013, elapsed/last=1.7360
k=24, elapsed=0.0024, elapsed/last=1.9031
k=25, elapsed=0.0048, elapsed/last=1.9879
k=26, elapsed=0.0086, elapsed/last=1.8034
k=27, elapsed=0.0182, elapsed/last=2.1088
k=28, elapsed=0.0361, elapsed/last=1.9787
k=29, elapsed=0.0730, elapsed/last=2.0242
k=30, elapsed=0.1419, elapsed/last=1.9442
k=31, elapsed=0.2844, elapsed/last=2.0040
k=32, elapsed=0.5733, elapsed/last=2.0154
k=33, elapsed=1.1388, elapsed/last=1.9865
k=34, elapsed=3.5476, elapsed/last=3.1152
k=35, elapsed=8.3034, elapsed/last=2.3405
k=36, elapsed=16.0347, elapsed/last=1.9311
k=37, elapsed=35.1934, elapsed/last=2.1948
```

Comment: You're spending all your time on building and hashing absurdly huge numbers, not on dict insertion. `1<<(1<<k)` quickly grows **absurdly** huge.

Comment: It would be very easy to create a class with a constant hash.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Only for a few specific types. Many classes still have extremely vulnerable hashes, including `int`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica AFAIK the hash of an integer is the integer itself. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L140

Comment: @nalzok: Yes (for small integers), which is extremely vulnerable. (The pattern for large integers is also static, regular, and extremely vulnerable, though that's not what's causing the slowdown in your tests.)

Comment: @khelwood I have edited the post to clarify that the keys must be integers. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dict insertion takes O(n) element comparisons worst-case, where `n` is the number of occupied entries in the table. Additionally, an individual insertion may require rebuilding the hash table, which may involve every element colliding with every other element all over again and take O(n^2) element comparisons.

Hash collision isn't what's causing the slowdown in your tests, though - your tests are spending all their time building and hashing absurdly huge integers. `1<<(1<<33)` is an entire gigabyte's worth of integer, for example.

It's fairly easy to construct adversarial input. For example,

```
In [4]: for i in range(20): 
   ...:     print(hash(i*(2**61-1))) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

you can just take multiples of `2**61-1`.

Comment: Just to add to this, when I tried the original code I hit a `MemoryError`. In my case the individual hashing didn't seem to take too long testing `hash(1<<(1<<30))`, but storing the  value did.

Comment: Multiples of `2*61-1` shows a O(1) complexity on my machine (I simply changed my code to use `dummy[k*(2**61-1)] = k` instead). Does the result looks quadratic on yours? Incidentally, I used `1<<n` to counter ["the other half of the strategy"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L189,L204), and took `n = 1<<k` to observe the trend better. In hindsight I did spent a lot of CPU time on constructing huge integers by doing that.

Comment: @nalzok: You're timing it wrong. Probably not running anywhere near long enough. You're probably also misreading the output, considering you thought the timings you originally posted were O(N^2) - the timings you originally posted are exponential, not quadratic.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica *the timings you originally posted are exponential, not quadratic.* Oops you are right, and it's indeed exponential with respective to `k`. Let me double check...